# how to make authentication in multiple apps using google developer console?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, google-authentication, google-developers-console

I want to make an android project using firebase as backend for it, the project contains multiple apps for admin,vendor,user and I know it's possible to add multiple apps in the same firebase project but is it possible to use one project and different apps in google developer console to add sha-1 for every app in it or what the best approach to implement that?

Comment: Yup, that should all be possible, and in fact fairly straightforward. Just create an app instance in the Firebase console, for each of your apps, and fill in the details. If you run into problems, please report back with details about what you did, and went wrong.